# How do I create a strong password string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, passwords

Would like to create a strong password in C++. Any suggestions?

- I assume it should use alpha (upper
  and lower), numeric, special
  characters.
- It would be good to be able to
  specify a minimum length.
- It would be great to avoid characters
  that are hard to visually distinguish
  like "O" and "O"
- It would be great to void all
  characters same, dictionary words,
  reversed words, names.

Any other tips? Where could I find code like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[APG](http://www.adel.nursat.kz/apg/download.shtml) (Automated Password Generator) implements all but your last requirement (no dictionary words / usernames / repeated characters).  It includes both pronounceable and fully random password generation algorithms.  Pronounceable passwords look something like this:

```
yevGaijra
clishahopp
jewnAms8
RacMevOm
Duheamch&
raicsant~
```

It's written in C and is available under a BSD-like license.

Cryptographically speaking, I'm not sure that your last requirement is valid...?  If the password generation is truly random, then a password of `aaaaaaaa` is just as likely as a password of `6-n&1jIK`, and if your attacker knows your algorithm, then by disallowing passwords like `aaaaaaaa`, you're reducing the attacker's search space.

Comment: I like the story about how the German Enigma crypto machine was broken in part by noticing that it never encrypted a plaintext character to the same ciphertext character, it *always* chose a different letter.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways.  The easy isn't necessarily the best

Create a string representing all the characters you want to define (meaning, no O's or 0s's, whatever), then fill a random-length string with random characters from that set.

The next step is to keep generating until you pass all assertions.  That is, check for dictionary words, reverse names, etc.

There will be times where generation takes longer than expected, but should still be faster than you can notice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [OpenSSL's random generator](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1264/generate-passwords-with-openssl/), then base64 encode it. (Won't get you all sorts of random characters, but will get you many.). It also won't do the similar character password bit though, sadly. My favorite generator is [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pctools.com%2Fguides%2Fpassword%2F&ei=D-VsSfDVCozAMcvk2egM&usg=AFQjCNEeees-AWn2siyPdmTGuNJNbHa3bQ&sig2=upiKOPd3YnGxmLsSNBWBEg), and it provides the features you're talking about. (Web-only, sadly)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a [TRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRNG) device plus some well [known algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_digest),
the best way lead with it ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are documented requirements that several sources use, such as [FIPS 181](http://www.itl.nist.gov/fipspubs/fip181.htm).

I would suggest looking at the documentation for the popular [Automated Password Generator](http://www.adel.nursat.kz/apg/) utility.  Looking at the options that it provides and the capabilities could go a long way for you.

Also, look at [checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength) your generated passwords so that they meet the threshold for your application.

Wikipedia also lists some [existing designs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) and standards.